# Couldn't assign different style for Bootstrap Rows

Tags: html, css, containers, styles, row

I have 2 Bootstrap class "Row" on a html page. When I change style of one of them, both are changed. I Tried to wrap it in a different container, but it doesn't work. (1 container has a position of absolute).

Help appreciated much !

Giorgi

Comment: Welcome to SO, to get the best answer for your question try to show up your code and what you have tried, so we can help you.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask